# Why match on a enum with a single variant for returning a static' str?

Tags: rust

This code is from rustc libsyntax/parse/token.rs:

```
pub enum SpecialMacroVar {
    CrateMacroVar,
}

impl SpecialMacroVar {
    pub fn as_str(self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            SpecialMacroVar::CrateMacroVar => "crate",
        }
    }
}
```

Why you would do that and not simply this instead?

```
impl SpecialMacroVar {
    pub fn as_str(self) -> &'static str {
        "crate"
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps for defensive programming reasons? If done the second way, it would erroneously return `"crate"` for *every* enum member even if more members were added to the enum later but you forgot to update `as_str()` to reflect that fact. This way, however, the compiler has a chance to catch these kind of errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps for defensive programming reasons? If done the second way, the function would erroneously return `"crate"` for every enum member even if more members were added to the enum later but you forgot to update `as_str()` to reflect that fact. This way, however, the compiler has a chance to catch these kind of errors.